# Algebra where $\infty = -\infty$ and $\frac{1}{0} = \infty$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$\infty = -\infty$ and $\frac{1}{0} = \infty$ and $\frac{1}{\infty}=0$

If one exists, what is the name of an algebra that has these properties?

I recall seeing an image of a closed circle where 0 and $\infty$ were on opposite sides, I think 1 and -1 were 90 degrees away from 0 and $\infty$ too.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory

Comment: Wheels and projective lines! It's coming back now. Thank you @Wojowu